# Fix masthead background on overscroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

## The Problem

I have a simple, full-width masthead at the top of my page, with a non-fixed background image (that is, `background-attachment: scroll`) and a bit of header text over it. It all looks fine, but when the user "overscrolls" upwards, the "overflow" is white. To solve this, I want to fix the position of the background when the user does this so that the content moves downwards but the background remains.

### Sample code

#### `index.html`

```
<div class="masthead">
  </div class="container">
    <h1>Hello, World</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### `main.scss`

```
/*...*/
.masthead {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/1900x1250/ff6666/000000');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
/*...*/
```

### Why `overscroll-behavior-y: none` won't do

Firstly, this feature isn't supported by Safari/WebKit yet, but I also think that this feels kind of aggressive. I quite like the feel of overscroll, and I would like to preserve this while still keeping the UI looking clean.

### Quirks

When I tried going about this myself, I found that adding the `background-attachment: fixed` property moved the positioning of the image slightly. Also, even when the background is fixed, the masthead doesn't extend into the overflow and thus its background remains white.

### I'm using

- `SCSS`
- `jQuery`
- `bootstrap`

Comment: Thank you for your well formulated question. Would you mind adding a little bit of code so we can see the structure of your document and SCSS?

Comment: @Queder thanks, just updated.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to fix the masthead while the overscrolling body does a rubber-band effect. I had to test this on an iPhone 5C because desktop browsers don't overscroll if you're not running OSX, so bear in mind these results are limited to an older version of iOS (10.something). These are my findings:

## Bad solution: changing the CSS on window scroll

You can add an event listener to the window scrolling event and fix the position of the masthead when the user scrolls over the top (*ie*, when the `window.scrollY` property is negative):

### CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.masthead {
    overflow: auto;
    /* move this div to a gpu-processed layer */
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); /* for iOS <8.1 */
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.fixed-top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
var masthead = document.querySelector(".masthead");
var mastheadHeight = masthead.clientHeight;
var topContentMargin = 16;
mastheadHeight += topContentMargin;

window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
    fixMastheadOnOverscroll();
});

function fixMastheadOnOverscroll() {
    let overscrollingTop = window.scrollY < 0;
    if (overscrollingTop) {
        masthead.classList.add("fixed-top");
        document.body.style.marginTop = mastheadHeight + "px";
    } else {
        masthead.classList.remove("fixed-top");
        document.body.style.marginTop = "0px";
    }
}
```

### Breakdown of the code

As you can guess, this code simply fixes the masthead to the top when the user overscrolls. A few nitty picky
points:

- `overflow: auto` on the masthead fixes collapsing margins when not overscrolling;
- adding `transform` is a known hack to promote an element to it's own layer and render it using the GPU. Does it make the positioning of the masthead any faster when overscrolling? I have no idea, this is just a suggestion to be worked on.
- adding a margin to the body when overscrolling makes the content render below the masthead; if you don't it will just render underneath the fixed masthead.
- since the content's top margin collapses when overscrolling, we add it's height to the body's margin so the user doesn't see the content jumping up and down when the body snaps back into place.

## Why is it bad?

As far as I know, firing a DOM-changing function when scrolling is costly. [From Twitter's own dev team](https://johnresig.com/blog/learning-from-twitter/#best-practices):

> It’s a very, very, bad idea to attach handlers to the window scroll event.

The event listener triggers the function almost continuously. There could also be some weird behaviour on iOS [due to Apple engineers making the callback fire only at the end of the scroll event](https://dzone.com/articles/why-scroll-event-change-ios-8) (I think).

## Good solution

¯\*(ツ)*/¯

Honestly, I have no idea how to go about this without using `overscroll-behaviour-y`. You could use the ugly hack above on iOS only by detecting the browser. There are a few performance improvments you could make :

- [throttle the callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll#Example), but this will probably lead to a laggy behavior;
- hard-code the masthead's height in `margin-top` in another CSS class and [use that class name on the body instead of changing the body style directly](https://www.quirksmode.org/dom/classchange.html), but that gives you way less flexibility.